# Mouse drifts when dragging in Linux Mint KDE on VMWare Fusion

Tags: kde, mouse, vmware

I'm using VMware Fusion with Linux Mint KDE (I think v13). The mouse works fine except for when I'm dragging something (e.g. resize or move a window). When I do that the mouse moves. Sort of like I click in one place and then it slowly drifts away a few pixels - like it is slowly snapping to a grid.

I don't think it's VMware - the mouse works fine in Windows VMs and in ubuntu gnome VMs. I think it might be some setting in KDE but I don't know what. What can it be?

**EDIT**

VMware Tools is already installed for this virtual machine.

Comment: the mouse drifts? or the windows? because there is a window setting that snaps to grid. mouse drift seems odd, but window drift not so much.

Comment: You're right - the mouse is fine, the window drifts. Where do I find that setting?

Comment: Although, scrollbars also do the same. If I move the mouse slowly then the scrollbar jumps like the window does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating `xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse` to version `1:12.9.0-0ubuntu0.1` (no need to specify the version though, just `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse` will do) seems to be the way to fix it. It worked for me!

For reference, I found out about it there:

- http://communities.vmware.com/thread/400750
- http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=206&t=108574